# Witcher 3 crashes every few minutes

Tags: pc, technical-issues, the-witcher-3

I just got Witcher 3 and was so excited to play it, but I can't enjoy it. The game crashes every few minutes (around 5 minutes) without a warning. I'm playing it on highest graphics but as it runs smoothly I guess the graphics aren't the issue. One time it crashed when a cutscene came up, another time in the middle of a fight.

My OS is Windows 8.1, I hope you can help me to get the game running

EDIT: Downvotes, telling me the reason would be helpful, thanks

Comment: Does it still happen when you reduce the graphical options? Could be your graphical card is running too hot on highest graphic settings and causing the game to crash.

Comment: I can't test it right now as I'm not at home, but I can try later. I have a GTX 970, maybe someone else with this card can relate.

Comment: Unless it's the same card, as in, your card with your pc and your environment they can't test it as it's, well, related to all those variables. - They might be able to note if it's common, I don't know.

Comment: Is your GPU overclocked at all? From what I have read, even the slightest overclock can make the game crash for whatever reasons.

Comment: My GPU is overclocked, and my game crashed once a day on average (i play about 5 hours a day on average).

Comment: Have you checked the latest drivers for your graphic card?

Comment: No, I never overclocked my GPU and yes I'm using the latest drivers.

Comment: Downvotes may be because the questions lacks any details or research. The downvote button has alt-text saying "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". You have literally stated that you get crashes, and that they happen at different times. Saying that you had tried something, or Googled, or tried x, y, and z would be very helpful (and make this question more acceptable).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the newest [NVIDIA drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx) 353.06 WHQL, I can finally run 'The Witcher 3' without crashes every 5 minutes!

I'm not sure, if switching off V-Sync and playing in full screen (native monitor resolution) mode was necessary too.

Comment: NVIDIA's 352.86 driver was awful, but 353.06 should do the trick now.

Comment: Nice (: I'll check it out and tell you if it works for me now too

Comment: I had the same issue with AMD Radeon 5700 crossfire.  Updating to Catalyst 15.5 fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

There are some reports that changing the framerate limit can help with certain types of crashed in this game. The most common solution I've heard about is to set the fps limit to unlimited, and either play that way or use an external program to limit the framerate.

There are some issues here, both with the game and with the newest Nvidia driver, which also tends to occasionally crash for me. I've a GTX 970 as well, and while it is far from unplayable, I also get reasonably frequent crashed. It is worse for me with the latest 1.05 patch. Downgrading is likely problematic as from what I've read the save games are not necessarily compatible with earlier game versions.

Answer (score 0):

I never over clock my video card, GTX 660ti, but also face a crash problem before, then my solution is download the MSI burner software, downclock a bit, mine one 40MHZ, then problem solve never face any crash since it.

Comment: Under-clocking seems like horrible way to fix a crash...(Even if it actually works) Plus this question already has an answer that doesn't involve modifying your hardware so it'd defiantly be better to try everything else before you go messing with your clock speeds.

Comment: Indeed, I've already accepted the answer that solved my problem. But thanks anyway even if this is a strange approach.