# How to prevent inventory crash?

Tags: pc, technical-issues, the-witcher-3

As soon as I access my weapon inventory and scroll down or click on a single item, The Witcher 3 crashes to desktop. (The other inventory tabs seems not to be affected - so far.)

Do you have any idea, how I can prevent this?

Is there any limit on items (total number of items, same items, same type of weapon) causing this?

What I have tried - with no luck:

- Starting the game with admin rights
- Rebooting the PC after crash
- Opening the weapon inventory with and without frame limit

I have already installed the newest NVIDIA drivers 353.06

Comment: Is it not possibly related to the issues you've previously had with drivers? https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/222756/witcher-3-crashes-every-few-minutes/222805#222805

Comment: I don't think so. The game runs 'ok' - as long I don't touch the weapon inventory. There are still some crashes, but not that I could repeat one of them. The inventory crash is 100% repeatable.

Comment: Once again I was able to workaround this specific crash setting the graphic quality to low. I really hope, that CD Projekt RED will fix this annoyance in a future patch.

Comment: I found that doing any sort of gpu overclocking made the witcher 3 unstable and crash all the time from any sort of event. Not sure if you are doing this or not.

Comment: For the crashes I see randomly, I give it a try. I have never overclocked my gpu by myself. But as far as I know, some GTX from NVIDIA has been sold already overclocked. I'm just not sure, how to 'underclock' it. I will have to search for a tutorial .-)

Comment: Try running the game in fullscreen instead of borderless window. It has helped me and others in making the game crash less often.